# Logic Bricks - Stop Sound Actuator

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, audio

I can start the song by pressing the <kbd>P</kbd> key but I can not stop the song being played. Logic Bricks are very confusing.

[image: logic bricks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that does not work is because of how the keyboard sensor works, it essentially is stopping and restarting the sound.

What you need to do is have a game property (A boolean set to true). The keyboard sensor is plugged into a *Property* actuator set to *Toggle*.

It is then that property that controls the sound actuator. Add a *Property* sensor, set its *Value* to "True", the *Property* to the game property created earlier, and leave the *Evaluation type* set to *Equal*.

In the end this is how the logic bricks should look.
[image: logic bricks]